# Python - how to check if weak reference is still available

Tags: c++, python, reference, weak

I am passing some weakrefs from Python into C++ class, but C++ destructors are actively trying to access the ref when the real object is already dead, obviously it crashes...

Is there any Python C/API approach to find out if Python reference is still alive or any other known workaround for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call PyWeakref_GetObject on the weak reference it should return either Py_None or NULL, I forget which. But you should check if it's returning one of those and that will tell you that the referenced object is no longer alive.

Answer (score 4):

From [Python C API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/weakref.html) documentation:

> PyObject* PyWeakref_GetObject(PyObject *ref)
>          Return value: Borrowed reference.
>      Return the referenced object from a weak reference, ref. If the referent
>      is no longer live, returns None. New in version 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

(Update compared to the older solutions)

We can call the reference and check if it is None:

`assert reference_object() is not None`, "object is dead"

From [weakref docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#:%7E:text=The%20original%20object%20can%20be,cause%20None%20to%20be%20returned.)