# Does Python GC relocate objects?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, cpython

In other words, is it safe for C code, given a reference to Python object to assume that, provided it called `Py_INCREF` on it, the pointer will not become invalid?

If you are wondering how this may happen: for example, Java GC is allowed to relocate objects in memory to prevent memory fragmentation.  This will, however, preclude you from using "raw" pointers to Java objects, since you may get a garbage reference.

---

Somewhat related: how can C code determine that Python object was garbage-collected, if it doesn't want to increase reference count (for example, if implementing `WeakKeyDictionary`)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300396/does-cpythons-garbage-collection-do-compaction

Comment: I'd ask two separate questions, the first question you're asking is answered by @NPE's link (**duplicate**) -- the second is answered by using the [`WeakRef` api](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/weakref.html) -- a possible dupe target for that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2993393/812183)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does CPython's garbage collection do compaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300396/does-cpythons-garbage-collection-do-compaction)

Comment: Per @AnthonySottile: Possible duplicate of [Python - how to check if weak reference is still available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993393/python-how-to-check-if-weak-reference-is-still-available)

Comment: @NPE and @ here thanks. I didn't know it's also called compaction, that's why I didn't find that. Good to know.